# Odoo 10 Filter for One2Many field not working

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have a question about the possibility to use a One2Many field in the search view for filter purposes.
Lets say I have this field here:

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit= 'account.invoice'

    custom_field_ids = fields.One2Many(
        comodel_name='account.payment.order',
        compute='some_method',
        readonly=True,
    )
```

Now I want to go ahead and insert a filter into the search view

```
        <record id="view_payment_order_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">view.payment.order.filter</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_account_invoice_filter"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <xpath expr="//filter[@name='refunds']" position="after">
                    <filter string="In Payment Orders" domain="[('payment_order_ids', '!=', False)]" />
                </xpath>

            </field>
        </record>
```

When I update the module then it doesnt give me any error. But the filter is not working. I did some research on this but there is no real "best practise" solution for this. What would be a good approach to enable the filter for this field. I basicaly want to show all invoices where this One2Many field is not empty.

Comment: In older version i had problems using `One2many` fields as computed fields. I tried to avoid them by using `Many2many` fields instead. And if you want to search on computed fields, you have to store them, which isn't easy in Odoo 10. What about an alternative? Have 2 computed fields: Many2many for showing the payments and a boolean stored computed field for the search (filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter with fields that are not stored. An workaround for this is to make a bool field stored based on your condition. Than add this field to search view as filter.

Comment: Yes I know. But then you have more and more problems. For example: If you make that bool field computed+stored then you have to define an api.depends on some field. If that field is non stored then your compute method will not be called. If you dont do compute+stored then you have to find some method or place in the code where you can set the boolean field. Otherwise you kinda have to do it with odoorpc

Comment: @Florent If it goes that far, and u cant do anything about that, you can do a cron job updating the bool field every some minutes for example. Not a good solution, but if filtering is important, you do have your result.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28299660)

Comment: @AmirDora.: In what way is this not an answer? It may not be the best solution, based on the OP’s feedback, but that’s what voting is for.

Comment: This answer could also be a comment because it is lacking details. It will be helpful for other users if the solution contains some code snippets as the lack of explanations is going to confuse people. @JeremyCaney